# let $(X,d)$ be metric space and $A$ subset of X if $r \gt 0 $ then the set $V_r(A)$ = {$x \in X : d(x,A) \le r$} is closed set.

Tags: functional-analysis

my attempt
$x \in X\setminus V_r(A)$ then $x \in$ {$x\in X : d(x,A) \gt r$} so there is  $\epsilon \gt 0$ s,t $B(x,\epsilon)$ $\subset X\setminus V_r(A) $
so $X\setminus V_r(A)$ is open then $V_r$ is closed
is this proof correct ?

Comment: The idea is correct

Comment: Try to figure out what value of $\varepsilon>0$ fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the (uniform) continuity of the distance function $d_A(x,A):=\inf\{y\in A:d(x,y)\}$. For fixed $x,y\in X$ and $z\in A$,
$$
d_A(x,A)\leqslant d(x,z)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z),
$$
and taking the infimum over the right-hand side yields
$$
d_A(x,A)\leqslant d(x,y)+d_A(y,A),
$$
so that
$$
d_A(x,A)-d_A(y,A)\leqslant d(x,y).
$$
By symmetry,
$$
d_A(y,A)-d_A(x,A)\leqslant d(x,y),
$$
so that
$$|d_A(x,A)-d_A(y,A)|\leqslant d(x,y).$$

Since
$$
V_r(A) := \{x\in X: d_A(x,A)\leqslant r\} = d_A^{-1}([0,r])
$$
is the preimage of the closed set $[0,r]$ in $[0,\infty)$ under the continuous map $d_A$ on $X$, it follows that $V_r(A)$ is closed.